# Residential 120V AC vs 12V DC

Tags: design, electrical, circuits, consumer-electronics

Can I repurpose residential LED lights (slim, 120V recessed) for my RV by directly providing them with 12V DC power, or is a more accurate approach required to bypass the existing circuit board?

Comment: depends on the voltage that the LED portion of the fixture requires

Comment: Yes, depends. Find out what the circuit board is doing.

Comment: You would essentially need to take apart the LED and redesign it for 12V. Some may be more suitable than others, no way to tell apart from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

a more economical and simpler method is to obtain LED *strip lighting* that is specifically engineered to run on 12VDC. these are available in bulk and are fairly cheap.